# Video rendering issue in Android 4.4+

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-videoview

`Android 4.4` and above taking too much time to render video on the splash screen.

here is my method to play video.

```
private void playVideo() {
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mVideoView.start();
            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {

            }
        });
        String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.animation_converted;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        if (mStopPosition != 0)
            mVideoView.seekTo(mStopPosition);
    }
}
```

tell me my mistake or give me any suggestion.

Comment: I just found out that It was bug of gradle version 2.0.+
change gradle verion back to 1.5 and issue will be resolved.